# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME on pdf

Tags: wordpress, pdf, pdf-generation, adobe

I am clicking on a link containing a href with pdf on my site. PDF opens in a new tab.
When I click the submit button on a form in a pdf file, I get an error
**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME mailto:tegramp@gmail.com.**
Could you help me with this issue?

PDF was created by Adobe Acrobat